# GLSL: Array lookup or bit operations performance

Tags: performance, glsl

I do not know how to measure performance with GLSL so I was wondering if you guys could help me out with this.

I have a 2-bit value and need to convert that into vec2 coordinates.

Which one is faster?

```
texture_coordinates = vec2(((index + 1) & 0x3) >> 1u, index >> 1u);
```

or

```
vec2[] lookup_array = vec2[4](
    vec2(0, 0),
    vec2(1, 0),
    vec2(1, 1),
    vec2(0, 1)
);

texture_coordinates = lookup_array[index];
```

I read array access is slow in GLSL but the other solution uses 4 operations, and I do not know which one is faster.

Comment: You have to measure it. Probably it depends on the hardware. Anyway, what is `index`? Is it an attribute? Is it the control variable of a loop?

Comment: @Rabbid76 ´index´ is a 2-bit integer that is passed in per-vertex. I have no idea how to measure GLSL performance, could you recommend any methods?